# Registered customer's shopping cart shows incorrect currency symbol

Tags: php

I have 3 stores configured in a magento website and set different currency for each store. The currency symbol displays correct in all areas except registered customer's shopping cart in admin page while the orders tab shows the correct symbol.In `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Tab\Cart.php` around line no:110 `'currency_code' => (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE)` gets the incorrect currency code. How to get the currency code for the customer registered store? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have get the currency code using the following code and It fixed the issue.

`$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
 $currencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore($customer->getStoreId())->getCurrentCurrencyCode();`